# Stop WildFly 10 programmatically

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10, mbeans

I am migrating from JBoss 6.1.0_final to WildFly 10. On a certain condition, I want to stop my server. Like:

```
if (condition == true) 
   System.exit(1);
```

The above code works fine in JBoss, it shuts down the server immediately.
But when I exeute the same in `WildFly10`, the server does not stop immediately.

It sends the shutdown signal, then unbound `datasource` then `JMX` and so on. I found can be done by MBeans but not working here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/198579. This gives some error like:

> params and description have different lengths

I want to stop my WildFly10 server immediately. Any one have done something like this?

Comment: Why don't you use jboss-cli or the management API for that ?

Comment: I want to stop it  programmatically.

Comment: Hum, how is that calling a rest API or using the client helper java code not a program ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (just handle the exceptions):

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.as:management-root=server");
mBeanServer.invoke(objectName, "shutdown", new Object[] { false, 0 }, 
        new String[] { boolean.class.getName(), int.class.getName() });
```

Comment: with above code, the error gone and server stop the processing ahead. but java still running since all threads related  to ActiveMQ are started. and after 1000 ms the timeout exception throws. And server still running. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can try stopping the Wildfly server using jboss-cli commands directly. Ensure that the server is up and running while you want  to stop it.

```
try {
    String jbossBinDir =  System.getProperty("jboss.server.base.dir").replace("standalone", "bin");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jbossBinDir+"/" + "jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=192.168.1.2  -c command=:shutdown");
    } 
    catch(IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```